# OpenSUSE equivalent of RHL /etc/sysconfig/network

Tags: linux

I have a startup script /etc/init.d/myscript that was written for RHL, but I need to convert it to work on OpenSUSE. The script starts out by referencing two RHL scripts:

/etc/init.d/functions
/etc/sysconfig/network

I've worked out that the first one is /lib/lsb/init-functions (I think - if I'm wrong let me know), but the second one is a directory in OpenSUSE, but it's a file in RHL. Where can I find the SUSE equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

There is not an equivalent. The information stored in /etc/sysconfig/network is scattered in some places on SuSE.
e.g:
- HOSTNAME: Defined on the file /etc/HOSTNAME
- GATEWAY: Defined as the default route in /etc/sysconfig/network/routes ( the entry that begins with default )